# Two reasons why $\int^{1}_{0}f(x) \,dx$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof

> Consider $f$ on $[0,1]$ defined as $f(0)=0$ $$f(x)=2^{-n}\quad \text{if}\quad 2^{-n-1}<x\le2^{-n},$$ for $n=0,1,2,3,...$
>   I'm looking for two reasons why $\int^{1}_{0}f(x) \,dx$ exists?

One of them could be because $f$ is a step function we can therefore integrate $f$ over $[0,1]$ and can calculate the integral. But what could be other reason for integral to exists?

Comment: 1) The function is *monotone* and (bounded) monotone functions [are always integrable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Monotone_Function_is_Riemann_Integrable). 2) The set of points where $f$ it discontinous is countable and therefore has measure zero (and is therefore integrable).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have an "infinite" step function (and this is abuse of the definition of a step function)  doesn't imply it's (Riemann) integrable. Consider the classical example $f(x)=1$ whenever $x$ is rational and 0 otherwise. The example is not considered a step function since it's not a sum over a finite number over intervals. If you want to show it's integrable (or not), you need to show that the supremum over lower sums equals the infimum over upper sums.

One idea is to show the function is a bounded and monotonically increasing, which are known to be always Riemann Integrable.

Comment: that's not a step function! And step function are always Riemann integrable

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal: left out a key word, thanks.

Comment: the example you mentioned is a simple function not a step function

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal: It's not a simple function, it's infinite.

Comment: the example you mentioned is a characteristic function and hence a step function

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal: simple functions are not necessarily riemann integrable though.

Comment: The definition of a step function requires the function to be written as a sum of characteristic functions of *intervals*.

Comment: @Winther: All of this is perfectly clear, except to OP who specifically called his function a step function in the question. Also points are just fine as intervals. That there is an infinite number of them is the key issue.